# remote-server-not-found (error code="404") XMPP

Tags: ios, xmpp, ios9, xmppframework

I am getting 404 error while adding user to contact using roster

Here is my code

```
NSString * buddyNameJID = @"vinod@192.168.1.45";

XMPPJID *jid = [XMPPJID jidWithString:buddyNameJID];
[[appDelegate xmppRoster] addUser:jid withNickname:@"vinod"];
[[appDelegate xmppRoster]subscribePresenceToUser:jid];
```

after this getting error

```
<presence xmlns="jabber:client" to="kishore@eswks45/5r493h8jj8" from="vinod@192.168.1.45" type="error"><error code="404" type="cancel"><remote-server-not-found xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas"/></error></presence>
```

I have checked so many sites so many question but didn't get any solution

Comment: depending on the situation, i can see you use local domain names, and a local ip. are they on the same network?

the xmpp server you are connected too, might not know the server.

Comment: Yes both are on same network

Comment: message is delivering sucessfully